# (REOPENED) Reopen the question on junior guy excited about his discovery?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question [How to handle a junior team member who excitedly talks about discovering something known to seniors for years?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/92468/3192) was put on hold because it appeared to be more of a rant. The OP did not clarify their actual issue despite multiple requests in the comments.

Nonetheless, HLGEM wrote a [good answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60206/dealing-with-inexperienced-and-arrogant-coworker) as a series of comments in the chatroom. That answer deserves better than getting lost in a chatroom. Hence, I made substantial edits to the question to remove the rants, if only to get HLGEM's answer in its proper place.

Please consider casting reopen votes if you agree.

Comment: I'd cast the final reopen vote, but I do wonder if the language is still a bit strong. "I'm agitated" and "How do I deal with such coworkers" seems like it would channel responses (and prompt downvotes). More professional or open-ended phrasing might help reverse some of those downvotes. EDIT: Actually, HLGEM's chatroom answer seems based on that rather arrogant attitude so perhaps this is worth keeping as is.

Comment: @Lilienthal Right I thought long and hard about softening the language even further, but one of the key points in the answer would include the OP's attitude as at least a part of the issue, so I decided to just cut down on the part where the junior is called arrogant, and not clean up the tone entirely. Unfortunately it means the question may still attract downvotes, I will try to think of a way to address both issues, and make a further edit if I find it.

Comment: @Lilienthal 4 reopen votes now.

Comment: @RichardU Thanks, final reopen cast.

Comment: That a Good answer exists or can exist is not a reason to reopen a bad question.  This is still a bad question.  Please reclose or edit into a constructive on topic question that isnt asking for general what to do.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings I attempted to edit to an on-topic question related to the behavior of the employee rather than the employee's experience itself. In doing so, I feel like to bring this question to an on-topic question, most of the question needs to be re-written, as it seems to be a rant based solely on the employee being referenced.